# Putting dynamic id in input path tag in spring

Tags: spring, jsp

I am putting text id and name dynamically

> but getting exception : org.apache.jasper.JasperException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither
>   BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name '"+mcFieldId+"'
>   available as request attribute

In ModdelViw I have added below fields

```
    Map<String, Collection<List<MapProgramFunctionField>>> programManageCustomerFields = getManageCustomerFields(userVo);

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("customer/manageMembership");
    model.addObject("programManageCustomerFields", programManageCustomerFields);
    model.addObject("customerVO", new CustomerVO());
    model.addObject("userVO", userVo);
```

`programManageCustomerFields` contains field details 
            Means it contains field id, name and also some other information.

I am putting those details dynamically using JSTL in jsp.

```
    <c:forEach items="${programManageCustomerFields}" var="pmcFieldMap">
        <c:forEach items="${pmcFieldMap.value}" var="mcFieldObj">

            <c:forEach items="${mcFieldObj}" var="mcFields">
                var mcFieldName = "${mcFields.fieldName}";
                var mcFieldId = "${mcFields.filedId}";  // firstName, lastName
                addAllInputs(filedType, mcFieldId);
            </c:forEach>

            var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
            newdiv.className = "clearfix";
            document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
        </c:forEach>
    </c:forEach>            


    function addAllInputs(inputType, mcFieldId){
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');

         switch(inputType) {
              case FieldTypeEnum.TEXT_BOX:
                   newdiv.innerHTML = label + "<form:input path='"+mcFieldId+"'/>";
                   break;
        }
    }
```

JSP Page ::

```
<form:form action="register" method="post" commandName="customerVO">
            <div class="add_user_form_wrapper2" id="add_user_form">
                <input type="hidden" id="programCardType"/>
            </div>
</form:form>        

CustomerVO Class

public class CustomerVO {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    // getter setter
}
```

Comment: Spring JSP tags are pieces of Java code, executed **at server-side**, to generate HTML. You can't use JavaScript, executed **in the broser**, to insert spring tags to the HTML. That makes no sense. The browser can't do anything with spring JSP tags.

Comment: What is the way to get it working?

Comment: Take a huge step back, and understand how all that is working. No shortcut.